# How to add pause to a Go program?

Tags: go

When i ever execute a Go Console program it just executes in one second, I've been looking on Google, the Go website and Stackoverflow.

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println()
}
```

It closes immediately when i execute it.

EDIT 2
actually i wanted the program to permanently stay paused untill the user presses a button

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can pause the program for an arbitrarily long time by using [`time.Sleep()`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#example_Sleep). For example:

```
package main
import ( "fmt"
         "time"
       )   

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello world!")
  duration := time.Second
  time.Sleep(duration)
}
```

To increase the duration arbitrarily you can do:

```
duration := time.Duration(10)*time.Second // Pause for 10 seconds
```

EDIT: Since the OP added additional constraints to the question the answer above no longer fits the bill. You can pause until the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed by creating a new buffer reader which waits to read the newline (`\n`) character.

```
package main
import ( "fmt"
         "bufio"
         "os"
       )

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello world!")
  fmt.Print("Press 'Enter' to continue...")
  bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadBytes('\n') 
}
```

Comment: But this only last for a few seconds, i want the program to exit when a key is pressed

Comment: @Vaderman2782 You didn’t mention that in the question. How Mike should have known?

Comment: @Vaderman2782 Added additional code for pausing until Enter key is pressed.

Comment: Nice Mike.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 28):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Press the Enter Key to terminate the console screen!")
    fmt.Scanln() // wait for Enter Key
}
```

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu the single comment in the code is all the explanation that is needed. What I find more questionable is that this is only a reduced version of Vas's existing answer without giving attribution.

Comment: Sory. I could not answer, since the reputation is <50 and I do not know English )
Comment... Ok, but is there much comment in the remaining examples, where they are definitely needed?
I'm use translater.

Comment: @Gimby It's much better than the other answer because it avoids the useless variable.

Answer (score 15):

The easiest another way with minimal imports use this 2 lines :

```
var input string
fmt.Scanln(&input)
```

Adding this line at the end of the program, will pause the screen until user press the Enter Key, for example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Press the Enter Key to terminate the console screen!")
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Scanln()
}
```

I use `fmt.Scanln` just one line.